# how to start rails server and gulp process by foreman

Tags: unix, ruby-on-rails-4, gulp, foreman, browser-sync

I've got Procfile:

```
job: bundle exec rake jobs:work
web: sleep 2; bundle exec rails s
```

I want to add Gulp to start with my server when I add Gulp before :web into Procfile like
this(default gulp task include BrowserSync task):

```
 gulp: gulp
```

and get error like this

```
[BS] Watching files...
18:00:39 web.1  | A server is already running.
```

I think this is because BrowserSync proxying :3000 port but rails server not starting at that moment.

Please give me advise or something to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, but in BrowserSync documentation the default port is set 3001 despite this you must config BrowserSync port to 3001 by hand.